# Suddenly receive 403 errors when trying to access files through browser (IIS)

Tags: iis, http-status-code-403, iis-8

I have a PHP application running on IIS 8.5, and up until recently users were able to view system generated PDFs by clicking a link.

All of a sudden we are receiving 403 error pages on these PDF links. I have verified that IIS_IUSRS has read permissions on the files and parent folders in question.

Here's the full error from the log files:

`2023-11-10 15:03:30 [ip removed] GET /PDFs/PDF-2023110813295.pdf - 443 - [ip address removed] 4 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/119.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 [url removed] 401 3 5 1541 0`

Comment: It may be that you need to grant read permissions on those files to all domain users

Comment: In the IIS Manager for the `PDFs` folder, do you have "Directory Browsing" enabled?

Comment: @ADyson this seems to have fixed it - I dont know how those permissions were removed though!